# operators under real vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $V$ is a real vector space, and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that $T_\mathbb{C}$ is invertible iff $T$ is invertible.

Can someone help me with this? what does it mean if $T_\mathbb{C}$ is invertible, and how should I relate it to back to $T$.

I'm trying to use the Fact that "w.r.t. the same basis in real vector space, the matrix representation of $T$ and $T_\mathbb{C}$ are the same", i.e., $\mathcal{M}(T)$$=$$\mathcal{M}(T_\mathbb{C})$, so does it mean that if matrix of one of it is invertible then the other one has to be invertible as well? Can I use that argument?

Comment: Can you include a definition of $T_\Bbb C$ in your question?

Comment: $T_\mathbb{C}$ is the complexification of $T$

Comment: Presumably one extends $T$ by $T (u+iv) = Tu + i Tv$. Note that $T(u+iv) = w+iz$ **iff** $Tu=w, Tv=z$.

Comment: ya I just solved it using injectivity argument thanks